# subset a data frame by row names of different rows

Tags: r, subset

I need to subset lines of data frame according their name. I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```
Name  plot  
12     25
22     23 
14     12 
16     22
23     54

DF.new <- subset(DF, rownames== c("12" , "16"))
```

Comment: `DF$Name` can be just `Name`

Comment: "Not working" isn't very clear. The specific error message or output would be more useful. Also a specific example of what you want the output to be (I'm assuming the rows where Name is 12 or 16?). Be careful too to check if the Name column is numeric or character. If it's numeric, you need to leave the quotes off the numbers when using %in%.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- data.frame(row.names=c("12a", "22a", "13a"), Name=c("12","22","13"), plot=c(25,18,9))
```

If you want to filter by the data frame column "Name", then:

```
DF.new -> DF %>% filter(Name %in% c("12", "16"))
```

If you want to filter by actual `row.names` of the df, then:

```
DF.new -> DF %>% filter(row.names(DF) %in% c("12a","13a"))
```

Or, using base R:

`DF.new -> DF[DF$Name %in% c("12","13"), ]` or

`DF.new ->  DF[row.names(DF) %in% c("12a","13a"),]`

Comment: However, this doesn't preserve output order.